# How to turn off the display via the command line?

Tags: command-line, display, power-management

Is there a way to turn off the display (enter power saving mode) using a command?

For example, when the computer is inactive for a specific interval, the screen turns off to conserve energy. Is there a way to manually turn off the screen, yet keep the computer running normally?

This is a notebook, so there's no 'power-off' button on the monitor itself.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
xset dpms force off
```

However, you need to make sure that your acpi is enabled. You can check this with

```
cat /proc/acpi/info
```

Another option could be

```
setterm -powersave powerdown
```

Comment: The first command didn't require sudo for me.

Comment: Me neither. _` ` ` `_

Comment: Sometimes the Enter keypress as you execute the command can be enough to immediately wake the computer back up again. I usually go with `sleep 0.2s && xset dpms force off` just to be safe. Also, this makes for a nice replacement for locking your screen: `gnome-screensaver-command --lock && sleep 2s && xset dpms force off`

Comment: ok.. took the sudo advisory out :D

Comment: I just did the same thing in kubuntu using info from this answer:  xdg-screensaver activate && sleep 2s && xset dpms force off

Comment: the first command works, but after some seconds the display turns on again!

Answer (score 7):

I'm running Ubuntu Server without X on a 2007 MacBook Pro. The display is sleeping by itself but won't reactivate when a key is pressed on the keyboard. At this point my fix is to use `vbetool`. Install using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install vbetool
```

Then use to turn display on via SSH from a different machine:

```
sudo vbetool dpms on
```

Or off:

```
sudo vbetool dpms off
```

Comment: vbetool is what I search for exactly! It turn the monitor off completely via BIOS VESA drivers/tools. Just like turning off by using hard key of the monitor!

Comment: doesn'^t work (macbook air old) mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted
Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface).

Comment: `Real mode call failed` - regular PC, Ubuntu 22

Answer (score 3):

I have made a unity launcher to turn off the LCD

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel

gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

It will open a small windows. Enter the following:

Name: `turnofflcd`

Command: `gnome-screensaver-command --lock && sleep 2s && xset dpms force off`

You can also choose an icon by clicking the icon on the left .

For more on making launcher see http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-create-desktop-launchers-in-ubuntu-11-10oneiric.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
(sleep 10; xset dpms force suspend) & xdg-screensaver lock
```

This starts the screen saver in locked mode and then puts your display in standby. Ubuntu Mate 15.10

Comment: In LUbuntu 18.04 the act of locking the screen wakes the screen back up!

Answer (score 1):

`xset dpms force off` worked only for 5 seconds.

I searched the internet and found the following script, and after a small change it worked perfectly.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import subprocess
from Xlib import X
from Xlib.display import Display
display = Display(':0')
root = display.screen().root
root.grab_pointer(True,
       X.ButtonPressMask | X.ButtonReleaseMask | X.PointerMotionMask,
       X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, 0, 0, X.CurrentTime)
root.grab_keyboard(True,
       X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, X.CurrentTime)
subprocess.call('xset dpms force off'.split())
#original
#p = subprocess.Popen('gnome-screensaver-command -a'.split())
#changed
p = subprocess.Popen('xset dpms force off'.split())
time.sleep(1)
while True:
   print display.next_event()
   p.terminate()
   break
```

Comment: In the above script the following lines are supposed to be comments only.  They need to be deleted OR commented with a #.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     original
p = subprocess.Popen('gnome-screensaver-command -a'.split())
changed

Comment: Lines 27,28,29 and 30.  Sorry, not used to the formatting in the comment section.  Usually I do not post.  But this time I thought this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I know that xscreensaver is not exactly blank screen, but may be of some help:

```
xscreensaver-command -activate
```

or via ssh

```
DISPLAY=:0 xscreensaver-command -activate
```

The same way deactivate:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xscreensaver-command -deactivate
```

or

```
export DISPLAY=:0 
xscreensaver-command -activate
xscreensaver-command -deactivate
```

Enter password after xscreensaver via ssh:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xdotool type Ctrl # wake up from screensaver
   or: DISPLAY=:0 xdotool click 1 
DISPLAY=:0 xdotool type "passwordovich"
DISPLAY=:0 xdotool type Return # Enter
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fails:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 30
```

... and then wait 30 seconds :-(

Note you must be logged in.

PS: values below 30 seconds seem silently bumped to 30 seconds?

Comment: @stumblebee (1) the question does NOT say "instantly"; so this _is_ an answer. Which happens to work and be useful. (2) Instantly is of course much better: that's why this answer starts with "if everything else fails".

Comment: You are correct.