# How can I put the display to sleep on screen lock?

Tags: lock-screen

When I invoke the "Lock Screen" action, is there a way to have the monitor go to sleep instantly? I'm aware of the power management setting to turn off the display after a set amount of time, but I want this to happen immediately.

I'm hoping there is a bash script that will lock the screen and put the display to sleep, and that I can have this invoked when a screen lock operation occurs.

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7295/how-to-turn-off-the-display-via-the-command-line) question for an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following script will check every ten seconds to see if the screensaver is enabled, and if it is, turn of the display using the command `xset dpms force off`.

It also checks to make sure it didn't already turn off the display, so you can unlock the screen without the monitor turning off while you are typing your password.

```
#!/bin/bash 

ALREADY_SHUTOFF="yes"

while true; do

    if (gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active");
    then

        echo $ALREADY_SHUTOFF
        if [ "$ALREADY_SHUTOFF" == "no" ];
        then

            # this command turns off the display
            xset dpms force off
        fi


        ALREADY_SHUTOFF="yes"

    else

        ALREADY_SHUTOFF="no"
    fi

    sleep 10

done
```

Comment: I tried `xset dpms force off` and it does shut off the display, but then it turns back on again after a few seconds.