# Monitors not staying OFF after some uptime, even with xset

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, power-management

I've had this issue with every version of Ubuntu I've tried over the past 8 years, whether running LXDE, Unity or XFCE.  Currently I'm running 17.04 with XFCE on a Dell Precision 7510 with a dock, and I've always had various Dell laptops.

**Preconditions**

At first monitors turn off correctly, either after configured timeout or if I issue **xset dpms force off** (which I have on a hotkey).  After a while (a few days of uptime) that no longer works, probably as a consequence of running some applications that force the monitors to stay on (vlc, yousician, chrome: youtube, etc).  The problem does not occur the first time I run them, but will happen after a while, even though the offending applications are no longer running.  Rebooting makes things work again, for a while, but is rather inconvenient (I normally reboot every 3-6 months).

**Problem**:

Once the above happens, the Screens stay on forever.  After issuing **xset dpms force off**, the monitor backlights turn off for a second or two, then come right back on.  Same results with **xset s activate** .

**Diagnostics**:

```
$ xset q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  20
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fa9fffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  10/1    threshold:  3
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 720    Suspend: 0    Off: 900
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

**Question**

What can I do to clear this "stay on" condition without rebooting?

Comment: Do you mean your monitors automatically awake with no reason, after that they don't sleep anymore, unless you restart you system?

Comment: @Redbob no, I mean what I said in the Problem section: Monitor backlights do not turn off for any length of time.

Comment: Ok , now I understood. What I meant about sleep and awake is turn off an turn on. Did you see [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20690/monitor-wont-enter-power-save-mode)?

Comment: @Redbob, thanks, but that page tells you how to do use xset the same way I'm trying to.

Comment: Did you solve this?