# Is there a programmable way to tell if the screen is locked?

Tags: gnome, programming, screensaver, crontab

I have lots of stuff in my crontab, including some that talks to my screen. If I'm not there for it to be notifying, I don't really want it to run.

Is there a way I can check to see if the computer is locked, so I can keep it from doing things when I'm not at my desk? Or, alternately, do other things *only* when I'm not at my desk?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run this command:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active"
```

if it has any output, the screen is locked.

In a shell script, you can use a clause like this:

```
if (gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active");
then
    ...
fi
```

<sub>(my thanks to DoR, who [originally posted these commands here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17679/how-can-i-put-the-display-to-sleep-on-screen-lock))</sub>

Comment: When you use `grep` in a test, its best to use `grep -q` so that there is no output to the console. Also the parenthesis are redundant - they cause a sub-shell to be created though there's no need for that in this case.

Comment: Testing it now to see if I can build on it. It seems to be somewhat fragile and inconsistent in first testing, but that might be just me.

Comment: On second thought, it seems to be starting to get together. Thank you.

Comment: You don't say "Thank you", but upvote, and mark it as 'accepted answer', when you're nice, please. :)

Comment: @VarLogRant no rush or anything, just to let you know, you can always change your mind about the accepted answer by just clicking the green check mark again to undo it

Comment: nowadays 2014, it only shows "is active" if the screen got blanked :(, I believe unity is actually doing the locking?

Answer (score 1):

**light-locker**

`light-locker-command -q`

or

`light-locker-command -t`

---

**xscreensaver**

You can watch the output of `xscreensaver-command -watch` or, if locking happens on blanking, use `xscreensaver-command -time`

---

See [unity - how to detect if the screen is locked?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505681/unity-how-to-detect-if-the-screen-is-locked/505741) for **gnome-screensaver-command** under Unity