# unity - how to detect if the screen is locked?

Tags: unity, lock-screen, screensaver, detect

both of these only work after the screen that was locked gets blanked; but they sometimes fail also, when for any reason the screen doesnt blanks...

```
gnome-screensaver-command --query
gnome-screensaver-command --time
```

I tried with `qdbus` also:

```
qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActiveTime
```

but it equally failed.

I just found that who actually locks the screen is Unity!

```
qdbus com.canonical.Unity /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.Lock
```

Related questions:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80143/how-to-create-a-daemon-which-would-be-listening-to-dbus-and-fire-script-on-messa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Aquarius Power's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/505741/527764) seems to work quite well. Here are some additions I might make to his solution.

#### Only querying lock state

If you simply need a one-liner to query the lock state, this should evaluate to true if locked and false if unlocked.

```bash
isLocked=$(gdbus call -e -d com.canonical.Unity -o /com/canonical/Unity/Session -m com.canonical.Unity.Session.IsLocked | grep -ioP "(true)|(false)")
```

---

#### Querying lock state *and* track time since last change in state

Now if you need to keep track of how long the screen has been locked you might want to take a different approach.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# To implement this, you can put this at the top of a bash script or you can run
# it the subshell in a separate process and pull the functions into other scripts.

# We need a file to keep track of variable inside subshell the file will contain
# two elements, the state and timestamp of time changed, separated by a tab.
# A timestamp of 0 indicates that the state has not changed since we started
# polling for changes and therefore, the time lapsed in the current state is
# unknown.
vars="/tmp/lock-state"

# start watching the screen lock state
(
    # set the initial value for lock state
    [ "$(gdbus call -e -d com.canonical.Unity -o /com/canonical/Unity/Session -m com.canonical.Unity.Session.IsLocked | grep -ioP "(true)|(false)")" == "true" ] && state="locked" || state="unlocked"
    printf "%s\t%d" $state 0 > "$vars"
    
    # start watching changes in state
    gdbus monitor -e -d com.canonical.Unity -o /com/canonical/Unity/Session | while read line
    do 
        state=$(grep -ioP "((un)?locked)" <<< "$line")
        # If the line read denotes a change in state, save it to a file with timestamp for access outside this subshell
        [ "$state" != "" ] && printf "%s\t%d" ${state,,} $(date +%s)> "$vars"
    done
) & # don't wait for this subshell to finish

# Get the current state from the vars exported in the subshell
function getState {
    echo $(cut -f1 "$vars")
}

# Get the time in seconds that has passed since the state last changed
function getSecondsElapsed {
    if [ $(cut -f2 "$vars") -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $(($(date +%s)-$(cut -f2 "$vars")))
    else
        echo "unknown"
    fi
}
```

Essentially, this script watches for changes in the lock state of the screen. When changes take place, the time and state is dumped to a file. You can read this file manually if you like or use the functions I wrote.

If you want a timestamp rather than the number of seconds, try:

```bash
date -ud @$(getSecondsElapsed) | grep -oP "(\d{2}:){2}\d{2}"
```

Don't forget the `-u` switch which forces the date program to ignore your timezone.

Comment: finally could test it, thx! thats why I like to not accept my own answer when I answer myself so better things may come out later :)

Comment: For `grep -ioP "(true)|(false)"`, this also works: `grep -oE "true|false"`

Answer (score 5):

the screen is actually locked by Unity, and, we need to use `gdbus`

```
gdbus monitor -e -d com.canonical.Unity -o /com/canonical/Unity/Session
```

this will show when it got locked like:

```
/com/canonical/Unity/Session: com.canonical.Unity.Session.LockRequested ()
/com/canonical/Unity/Session: com.canonical.Unity.Session.Locked ()
/com/canonical/Unity/Session: com.canonical.Unity.Session.UnlockRequested ()
/com/canonical/Unity/Session: com.canonical.Unity.Session.Unlocked ()
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar, but how to do this without the monitoring? like just query'ing?

Comment: the only option I found was to keep it monitoring (may be there is a way to just query, but I couldnt find despite I tried), I guess it is because the moment the screen is locked is not stored anyewhere, so the monitor would be the only way to show when it happens.

Comment: I mean, try too, if you find, tell me, or add an answer :D

Comment: Ah haha ok ill try to find it im not good with linux im a windows guy :P im just coding some cross os stuff so searching the internet.

Comment: @Noitidart http://askubuntu.com/a/890802/46437 :)

Comment: Thank you so so much @AquariusPower for the ping! This was still an issue for me!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531682/login-to-front-end-gui-from-ssh-together-with-synergy/533986#533986)

and the help I got was similar to what Aquarius Power said before, except that it was included in a bash scrip daemon, that can run in the background.. I found it very helpful. so, have a look at my Question, and answer, and see if this helps you also.