# Skip notify-send job if screen locked?

Tags: 18.04, scripts, ubuntu-gnome

I have a cron which runs a script every hour, it uses a notify-send for a notification on the Ubuntu 18.04 desktop (Gnome) once it starts.

What can I add to the script to:

1. If screen is locked then exit.
2. If screen is not locked then continue as normal with notification.

The answer below lead me to depending on environment:

```
$ qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive

$ qdbus org.kde.screensaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive

$ qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unity - how to detect if the screen is locked?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505681/unity-how-to-detect-if-the-screen-is-locked)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix not a duplicate, 18.04 doesn't use Unity.

Comment: 18.04 uses Unity when upgrading from 16.04 and Unity can be added to any 18.04 installation but, I understand your point.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix and you missed where I explicitly stated "Ubuntu 18.04 desktop (Gnome)".  :)

Comment: I should know better than to argue with a Princess :P. I've retracted my close vote and posted an answer to know which Desktop Screen Saver is active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting to hide notifications while the lock screen is enabled:

[image: GUI settings]

You can also modify this setting via the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-in-lock-screen false
```

But, since you asked, you can also use `gdbus` on the command line with the `--session` parameter and `org.gnome.ScreenSaver` to determine if the screen is locked.

Answer (score 0):

## Test if screen saver is active

`qdbus` will tell you if the screen saver (used by Lock Screen) is active. First you need to know which environment you are using: Gnome, Unity, KDE, etc.

In this example, Unity is active whilst Gnome and KDE are not:

```
$ qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive
false

$ qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive
Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod
No such interface 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' on object at path /ScreenSaver

$ qdbus org.kde.screensaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive
Service 'org.kde.screensaver' does not exist.
```

For the Gnome desktop the second option will return `false` and an error message will appear for the first and third options.