# Is there a programmable way to tell if the screen is locked with the new Unity interface?

Tags: unity, cron, programming, screensaver

I have lots of stuff in my crontab, including some that talks to my screen. If I'm not there for it to be notifying, I don't really want it to run.

Is there a way I can check to see if the computer is locked, so I can keep it from doing things when I'm not at my desk? Or, alternately, do other things only when I'm not at my desk?

Yes, [I asked this question before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35243/is-there-a-programmable-way-to-tell-if-the-screen-is-locked). I am now on Ubuntu 14.04 and Unity, and the environment has changed. When I run `gnome-screensaver-command -q`, I get `The screensaver is inactive` whether the workstation is locked or not. A new environment requires a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through the packages mentioning `unity` (`apt-cache search unity`), ignoring anything with `lib`, `lens`, etc. in the name. [`unity-services`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/unity-services) caught the eye. One of the files in this package is `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/unity-panel-service-lockscreen.conf`, an Upstart job containing:

```
description "Backing Service for the Unity Panel"
author "Andrea Azzarone <andrea.azzarone@canonical.com>"

start on desktop-lock
stop on desktop-unlock

respawn
exec /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service --lockscreen-mode
```

As you may have guessed, this job is run when the screen is locked. This gives you a couple of options:

### Check if the command in the `exec` line is running:

Check whether `/usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service` is running with `--lockscreen-mode` option. Note that `unity-panel-service` is always running, but when you lock the screen, another instance is started with that option. So something like:

```
if pgrep -cf lockscreen-mode
then 
    # do stuff
fi
```

[`pgrep -f`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pgrep.1.html) searches the complete command line, so we can search for the option.

I think in this case the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/unity-panel-service.1.html) of `unity-panel-service` is wrong or outdated. It says:

> **unity-panel-service** takes no options.

---

### Use an Upstart job

You can work off the above job configuration to write your Upstart job. Create a [session job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job) (say `some-job`) `~/.config/upstart/some-job.conf` containing:

```
description "Some script to be run when screen gets locked"

start on desktop-lock
stop on desktop-unlock

script
    # do stuff
end script
```

A converse script with the `start` and `stop` events swapped can be used to run things when the screen is unlocked.

Comment: Am putting the pgrep -cf version into my scripts for now, but setting up the upstart to set something like ~/.is_locked to "true" or "false" and reading that file? I like that. But I'm away from my workstation, so that'll have to wait.